# How to create a transaction between google cloud storage and database handling exceptions

Tags: java, transactions, google-cloud-storage

When using google cloud storage client you can create and delete for example an image from the google storage. 
The two methods create and delete do not throw exceptions. Are exceptions like for example a connection problem handled by the google cloud client?

It seems these functions return the actual object or null/false in case something bad happens. Right?

This is the code I am using to create and update the image url in a database:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId("project-id").build().getService();

BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(userImage.getContentType()).build();

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String path = uuid.toString();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", path);

try {
    Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, userImage.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

user.setImageUrl("https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket" + path);
this.userRepository.save(user);
```

I want to be sure that the create happened and that the url was commited in the database when returning from this function.

I would also like to add the following:

When adding I would like to remove the last image using the url in the database before updating.

But again here I would like this to happen all of it or nothing.

And it seems that I can create the image and not being able to save the url and loose the image in google storage. The same can happen when deleting. You delete the image for example but then you can't update the image url in the database and I will have a broken image in the frontend for example.

So, how can I implement sort of a transaction including the addition of the new image and url and the deletion of the old image and the old url.

Or what other mechanism, solution can I investigate? That give me this guarantees?

Can you help me and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry I can't help with your question but I was wondering if you had any issues with needing to create a thread when doing this?  I'm currently trying to save an image to a bucket and encountering all sorts of issues, your pasted code looks far simpler than mine making me wonder if I've screwed something else up

Comment: @null, could you please share your issues in a separate question, in case you haven't done so already? The community can help you more easily then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the google cloud storage client deals with the exceptions and only returns null or the actual blob.

So the idea is to save the image url and id in the database and create the image in the google cloud storage deleting the last image in the google cloud storage. (I just keep one image for each user).

I came up with the following.

You create a transaction that creates the record with the new url.

And then you create the image in the google cloud storage.

If the creation of the image and the update in the database goes well everything fine.

If a problem arises when saving to the database you just abort the transaction and you do not create. The same way if google cloud storage returns null (couldn't save the image) you throw an exception and rollback the transaction. And so everything stays as it was.

To delete the last image in the database (url) and in the google cloud storage in the beginning of the transaction you also create a record in a "delete old images" table with the last url.

I created a task that runs periodically and sees if there are urls in that table and issue a delete in the google cloud storage (gcs). I am also using a transaction here because you want to delete the record and issue the delete in the gcs. If everything goes well nice, otherwise you rollback and the next time you run the task again you try again to delete it.

That's it. If you think I could have approached this differently and better please tell me.